# Referencing previous rows in SQL without fetching

Tags: sql, rows, lag

Is there a way to reference a previous row (or multiple rows) using a function like LAG() in the select statement without fetching the rows in the results? I want to check if there are instances where a row with the same subject name and label (different columns) have record counts > 85 three times in a row as the record counts are taken every 5 minutes, then create a column holding the values 'TRUE' or 'False'. However, I only want the true or false value to be next to the distinct subject name and label combination where the record count value is the MAX(recordCount) for that combo.

```
select Distinct n.SUBJECT 
,n.label
,cast(cast(max(a.RecCount) AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) / 100 AS DECIMAL(10, 2)) AS MaxRecCount 
,"Red" = 
CASE 
    when n.label = lag(n.label,1) OVER(Partition BY n.label ORDER BY n.label)
     and cpu.RecCount >=85.00
     and LAG(cpu.RecCount,1) OVER(Partition BY n.label ORDER BY n.label) >=85.00
     and LAG(cpu.RecCount,2) OVER(Partition BY n.label ORDER BY n.label) >=85.00
        then 'TRUE'
        ELSE 'FALSE'
END 
from n, cpu
group by n.subject, n.label, cpu.reccount
```

This returns TRUE of FALSE for the original RecCount and the previous 2 records, but I only want TRUE or FALSE to reference if the record count exceeds 85 3 times in a row at any point during data collection, and place the TRUE or FALSE value in a the new column "Red" next to the max() RecCount of the specific subject, label combination.

Comment: Is there no datetime column you can use to see how many records were created in the 5 minute time period?

Comment: This is not MySQL.

Comment: @JacobH , there is a datetime column yes, but how does that help?

Comment: Are you not trying to count the number of records with the same name and label in a 5 minute time period? Maybe I am not understanding the requirements.

Comment: @JacobH I want to see if the count is greater than 85 three times in a row, and if yes then put value TRUE, else FALSE, but only have it return the max value for all records with the distinct subject and label combination